# Internet Explorer Browser Issue Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems with viewing a landing page I designed using Bootstrap, within Internet Explorer all versions.  There are 6 boxes at the bottom of the page which should typically sit three across the content container.  However, when in Internet Explorer there is an extra display box being displayed. The website URL is: www.newcastleswimmingpools.com -  My HTML is below:

```
<div class="row span12">


    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">



        <img src="/img/Colours.png" alt="Outstanding Colour Range" />
        <center><a style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="http://www.barrierreefpools.com/colour-range"><h4>Wide Color Range</h4></a>
        <p>Boasting six shimmer colours combined with three royal colours you can be assured we have a colour for you. Barrier Reef Pools pride themselves in only using a marine grade gelcoat (ISO NPG.), ensuring the surface in the contact with pool water is the best.    </p><br/><br/>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">



            <img src="/img/25yr.png" alt="Manufacturer Warranty" />
            <center><h4>Manufacturer Warranty</h4>
            <p> Barrier Reef Pools offer a 25 year structural warranty with their pool shells. There is also an internal warranty which meets SPASA Guidelines and Australian Standards, as opposed to concrete pools which at best, will guarantee a seven year structural warranty.</p><br></center>
            <br/>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">


            <img src="/img/5tick.png" alt="5 Tick of Approval" />
            <center><h4>5 Tick Certified Product Award</h4>
            <p>Barrier Reef Pools Newcastle is the only Fibreglass Swimming Pool provider to be awarded the '5 tick' Certified Award.  This proves that you are purchasing quality when you choose Barrier Reef Pools for your next fibreglass swimming pool.</p>
            </center>
            <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">
            <img src="/img/splash.png" alt="Quick as a Splash Installation" />
            <center><h4>Quick As A Splash</h4>
            <p>From our manufacturing plant straight to your home, your Barrier Reef Pool arrives ready to install. No fuss installation in as little as seven days, compared with concrete rendered or pebbled pools which can take up to three months to complete.</p></center>
            <br>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">



            <img src="/img/Ranges.png" alt="Our Pool Range" />
            <center><h4>Pool Range</h4>
            <p>Development and expansion of our modern shapes and sizes is constant so that our range of pools is second to none. With an 800m2 facility dedicated to new pool development ensures that you will have a choice of the very latest designs and features to suit your lifestyle.  </p></center>
            </center>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="span4">
    <div class="contentbox">


            <img src="/img/LookingGood.png" alt="Looking Good" />
            <center><h4>Looking Good</h4>
            <p>Pools feature a super soft high gloss surface in a fantastic range of vibrant shimmer and royal colours. This ultra-hard wearing surface is non-porous, stain and chemical resistant and of course is so easy to maintain and clean.</p></center>
            </center>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>  



    </div><!--EndRow-->
```

CSS:

```
.contentbox {
height:300px;
  margin-bottom:30px;       
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

It is something probably super simple I am missing to allow for Internet Explorer to render properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to put both "row" and "span12" classes on the same <div>. Remove the "span12" and see what happens. See the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

...I also noticed you have some misaligned tags ( </p> at line 87, </div> at 910, </center> at 955 and 967).

Make sure to validate with [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) before doing anything else ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried to above advice with no luck.  The phantom random box is still there when viewing.

Comment: @jose is right about the row. Each row needs to equal 12. Also the HTML errors are probably contributing to the phantom behaviors. IE is not as forgiving as other browsers. [Invaluable tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

Comment: Hi thanks for a prompt reply - I have fixed the below as stated however the phantom box still in IE is dislpaying.  you can view it here: www.newcastleswimmingpools.com/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I noticed you didn't specify a DOCTYPE. Bootstrap runs into issues like line-height when you don't, so at least be sure to add:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
```

to the top of your document.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a site responsive, use the class row-fluid, otherwise just row
the grid of bootstrap is 12.
if you want 3 boxes in a line, your class span name must be span4, because 4*3=12
if you want 4 boxes in a line, your class span name must be span3, because 3*4=12
you got it? :)

remember that bootstrap 3.2 is no longer support

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  /* 4*3 = 12 */
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
  /* 4*3 = 12 */
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
  <div class="span4">the content</div>
</div>
```

hope this help